# Higher dimensional Euclidean geometry problem

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, linear-programming

In my engineering/physics research, I am facing one math problem which I believe should be well established in mathematics...

I have a linearly spanned space given by the column vectors of the following matrix:

[image]

I want to find the intersection of this space with the first quadrant of the 16 dimensional space (meaning Sum(a[i]*e[i],with a[i]>0),i=1..16). Is there a general algorithm or software package that could do this?

I also wish to know the fundamental knowledge involved, which kinds of book shall I look at?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is called linear programming.  Every vector in the subspace is a linear combination of the given column vectors, and the requirement to be in the first orthant is the same as requiring that the coefficients of this linear combination obey certain linear inequalities.